# Pandas: groupby and then retrieving IQR

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, quantile

I am quite new to Pandas and I am trying to do the following thing:

I have two dataframes `comms` and `arts` that look like this (except for the fact they are longer ad with other columns)

comms:

```
ID    commScore           
10       5                
10       3                  
10      -1                 
11       0                
11       2              
12       9      
13      -2     
13      -1     
13       1      
13       4
```

arts:

```
ID    commNumber
10        3 
11        2    
12        1
13        4
```

I need to group `comms` by their ID, and then save in `arts` (obviously in the correct ID line) the interquartile range (*IQR*) of the commScore distribution for each ID.

I've already tried using `groupby`, `agg` and `map` , but since my notions of `pandas` are quite limited, I just couldn't do what I was looking for.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Andrea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can `group` the dataframe by `ID` and aggregate column `commScore` using the function [`iqr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.iqr.html) from `scipy.stats` to calculate inter quartile range, then `map` this calculated `iqr` range on the column `ID` of the `arts` dataframe

```
from scipy.stats import iqr

arts['IQR'] = arts['ID'].map(comms.groupby('ID')['commScore'].agg(iqr))
```

---

```
   ID  commNumber  IQR
0  10           3    3
1  11           2    1
2  12           1    0
3  13           4    3
```

Answer (score 3):

The `GroupBy` object has a `quantile` method. You can calculate Q3 and Q1, and subtract them. Some renaming and joining follow it:

```py
grouper = comms.groupby("ID")
q1, q3 = grouper.quantile(0.25), grouper.quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1
iqr = iqr.rename(columns={"commScore": "IQR"})

arts = arts.set_index("ID").join(iqr)
```

to get

```
>>> arts

    commNumber  IQR
ID
10           3  3.0
11           2  1.0
12           1  0.0
13           4  3.0
```

If there is more than one numeric column, then we go explicit about `commScore` as:

```py
grouper = comms.groupby("ID").commScore
q1, q3 = grouper.quantile(0.25), grouper.quantile(0.75)
iqr = q3 - q1
iqr.name = "IQR"  # `iqr` will be a series since we selected 1 column,
                  #  so renaming is a bit different

arts = arts.set_index("ID").join(iqr)
```

which gives the same result.

If you don't want to call `quantile` 2 times, you can pass a list `[0.75, 0.25]` and then subtract them with `agg`. So instead of 2 lines above involving `q1` and `q3`, we write

```py
iqr = grouper.quantile([0.75, 0.25]).groupby("ID").agg(np.subtract.reduce)
```

and the rest is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how does python understand that I want to compute the quantile for the ```commScore```variable in line 2 of your code?

Comment: @Sala It applies to all the numeric columns left after grouping by ID. In this case, there is only `commScore`.

Comment: Actually I have more than one numeric column that I didn't report here

Comment: @Sala I edited to account for that if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Mustafa. If I can ask, where did you learn about all this "advanced" use of pandas?

Comment: Oh, @Sala my knowledge is not advanced at all; if you are looking for advanced, the other answerer Shubham is the way to go :). But my two cents are: reading official documentation of Pandas, reading the top-rated and frequently visited answers here, trying to answer pandas questions here to practice, and of course learn from the great answers (e.g. Shubham's above answer; or any of his answers, really :)) should get us going. It takes time, of course.

Comment: Thaks for your detailed answer! From now on, I will try to do so. Cheers